# Compare code date to sql date ASP NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I get the error about convert type date when i try to compare this :

Page Load :

```
Dim DataCorrenteLoad As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Label2.Text = DataCorrenteLoad
```

and in SqlDataSource the where condition is that the FinishDate >= Today date

How can i solve this situation ? Should i change the format dd-mm-yyyy ? Or what ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Did you include that line in your question? Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe try to Dim a separate variable for Date and then convert to string in a separate variable and line.

Comment: Date is a date and nothing else! You should use date, not string!

Comment: If i put Date instead String, the label show : 13/06/2017 , and in the database the date is for example : 2017-05-05

Comment: You're talking about string representation of date, but not on date! Date is not equal to its string representation.

Comment: Yes , i know. But how can i work with database date and asp net date ? the format is different

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano not if you load the DB field value into a DateTime object using a cast. Assuming the DB field has a Date type and not just a string. Compare a DateTime with a DateTime. Don't attempt to do string comparisons.

Comment: Let me try, at the moment , thanks to all.

Comment: I feel like your question is missing some context - however you could try to change format to DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: Are you comparing a string with a date, two date or two strings? Are you concatenating your query?

Comment: Show the code using the SqlDataSource. Changing your format is the ***absolute last*** thing you should do. You need a valid SqlParameter using the DateTime object. We need to see how you use hte SqlDataSource to show you how to do that.

Comment: The important part of sql data source is the where condition and i wrote it in my post. Anyway now i have understand that i have to study more teory about date and syntax. Thanks to all guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, you want to compare dates, but you kept your focus on string representation of a date. This is not the same!

Take a look at example:

```
Dim DatabaseDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)
Dim CurrentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today
 'case 1: compare and display date in current culture - depending on regional settings
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} equal to {2}", DatabaseDate.ToString("d"), If(DatabaseDate=CurrentDate, "is", "is not") , CurrentDate.ToString("d"))

'case 2: change string representation of date:
'compare dates in France and German format
Dim cu1 As Globalization.CultureInfo = New Globalization.CultureInfo("Fr-fr")
Dim cu2 As Globalization.CultureInfo = New Globalization.CultureInfo("De-de")
DatabaseDate = DateTime.Today
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} equal to {2}", DatabaseDate.ToString("d", cu1), If(DatabaseDate=CurrentDate, "is", "is not") , CurrentDate.ToString("d", cu2))
```

Above code returns:

```
'case 1
2017-06-08 is not equal to 2017-06-13
'case 2
13/06/2017 is equal to 13.06.2017
```

**Conclusion:**
*Depending on OS regional settings, the date format may differ, but the date is still the same!*

For further details, i'd strongly recommend to read these:
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)
[Parsing Date and Time Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime)
[Design and Implementation Guidelines for Web Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647353.aspx)
[Formatting Date and Time for a Specific Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Label2.Text= System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");

use this it will work System.DateTime.Now will show current time when you use To strong("dd-mm-yyyy") it will convert it in to string and set it's formate which u set under double quotes.

Comment: Just adding the code will not be helpful, add some explanation too

Comment: Wrong approach!